# Find value in a table column with IN query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have data in a database column in a json format. i want to write a query that where there will be pSpecialPrice will be "1" fetch that products from the database only...

I write a query but its not working..

here is data in json format in table.

```
{"pName":"BB8GB OTG USB Flash Drive for Smart Phone/Tablet PC Rose Red","pID":"1","pSKU":"81010229","pShortDescp":"BB8GB OTG USB Flash Drive for Smart Phone/Tablet PC Rose Red","pLongDescp":"BB8GB OTG USB Flash Drive for Smart Phone/Tablet PC Rose Red","pURL":"8gb-otg-usb-flash-drive-for-smart-phone-tablet-pc-rose-red","pCountry":"","pStatus":"1","pPrice":"9.99","pspecialPrice":"1","pDiscount":"25","pspDate":"11/11/2015","pDealDisc":"","pdealDate":"","pmetaTitle":"8GB OTG USB Flash Drive for Smart Phone/Tablet PC Rose Red","pmetaDescp":"8GB OTG USB Flash Drive for Smart Phone/Tablet PC Rose Red","pmetakeys":"8GB OTG USB Flash Drive for Smart Phone/Tablet PC Rose Red","pImgLabel":"8GB OTG USB Flash Drive for Smart Phone/Tablet PC Rose Red","pStock":"26","pproStatus":"1","pLimitPerson":"5","product-color":"Blue","submit":"Submit"}
```

QUERY I WROTE :

```
SELECT * FROM `Table_Name` WHERE `Column Name` IN ("pspecialPrice":"1")
```

Can any one help me to sort this out ..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: @Fred-ii- i know simple In query, but this time i want to to use in query inside a Json array..so let me know how to find value from such arrays in mysql query

Comment: `WHERE INSTR('Column Name', '"pspecialPrice":"1"') > 0` or `where match(Column Name) against ('"pspecialPrice":"1"')` - add the ticks for `Column Name`.

Comment: If you want to do any kind of interrogation of the json data in MySQL, then it seems sensible to store it as normalized data. It's pretty quick and easy to flick back and forth from one to the other

Comment: so, none of the above work (or not)? `FIND_IN_SET()` is another.

Comment: you've been given answers/comments. What works and what doesn't isn't known and whether this question will be closed. @ me if you need me, I am moving on. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't want it. It will be better to parse JSON and store contents in some relational table. But if you can't change architecture or still need this, use `LIKE`.

```
SELECT * FROM `Table_Name` WHERE `Column Name` LIKE '%"pspecialPrice":"1"%'
```

**UPD>**

I think it will be better to put you JSON data to table with this structure, let's call it `json_values` for example:

```
tab_id  name          value
1       pName         BB8GB OTG USB Flash Drive
1       pspecialPrice 1
```

Where `tab_id` is primary key from your table, `name` is key from JSON data and `value` is value from `JSON`. You will need to add index on fields `name` and `value` from this table. Than you can find some item like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `Table_Name` t
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM `json_values` v
                WHERE t.id = v.tab_id
                  AND v.name = 'pspecialPrice'
                  AND v.value = '1')
```

This solution will be much faster and still scalable, you can add any field and still be able to search items using normal SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table_Name` WHERE `Column Name` LIKE "%pspecialPrice%"
```

However this is a bad idea (performance issues and your data is not normalized). Better store the fields you want to query separately. This way they can be indexed and thus searched for faster.

Comment: I agree with you. but every field is adding custom from database.. so it was getting so tough to manage the field and content.. so i saved the data in array and saved...

Comment: Maybe you could offer two possibilites to search for: one with often queries (price, name, etc.) and one extended search over all fields. Additionally, you might want to use some binding mechanism, this way, you do not have to specify each field separately (instead use an array, that is).